# Como negar acceso a un directorio en XAMPP

Tags: xampp

Tengo un problema, cualquier usuario o persona puede acceder a mis carpetas o directorios desde su navegador, mostrándole todos mis archivos. Necesito negar el acceso público pero no sé hacerlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. En el directorio Apache2 debes encontrar el archivo conf/httpd.conf. Allí debe haber una etiqueta <Directory ... >...</Directory> que especifica tu directorio público. Algo más abajo debe haber algo como `#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>` Si no lo encuentras agrégalo. Y, crea un archivo index.html en los directorios que quieras ocultar cuyo único contenido en el body sea "privilegios insuficientes" o lo que quieras decir al que abra el directorio.

Comment: Me funcionó, pero no habría forma de evitar el acceso a directorios completamente (ej. a la carpeta ms-swf junto con el resto de carpetas como c_images, dcr, etc..) desde htaccess o crossdomain.xml?

Comment: En las directivas de <Driectory ...> ... </Directory> se pueden imponer restricciones de acceso. No tengo a mano el manual de apache para indicarte cuales son.